# "On the minute" vs "after a minute"

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning in the following context.

> After you complete the excercise, you can do it again **on the minute**/**after a minute**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the minute** refers to the punctuality of the routine.

> Do five sets of three lifts, on the minute.

That would mean that each of the five sets should commence when the second-hand of your analogue watch reaches 60 (or your digital watch reaches the next minute)

**After a minute** refers to a stretch of a minute, here, a rest between sets.

> Do five sets of three lifts.  Do the first set, and then each subsequent set should be done after a minute (i.e. of when the previous set finished).

In this context, **on the minute** would be used when the goal is to set a very regular, even pace.  **after a minute** would be used when you want to emphasize that a rest is needed between finishing one set and beginning the next.

Compare different contexts:

> Buses arrive on the hour.
>
> You've just eaten. Don't go swimming until after an hour.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please give more examples with phrase "on the minute"? I cannot really get its meaning. I asked a question about it but it is still murky to me

Comment: Do you understand what the word **punctuality** means?

Comment: Yes, I do understand it. It is getting clearer to me

Comment: So that mean that If do 5 sets of three on the minute, then the rest between sets would be less than a minute. For example: if I begin a set at 45 minute, then the second one I wil begin at 46. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, with five sets of three, if the set begins "on the minute",  the rest between the third lift and the first lift of the next set occurs within the minute. If each lift of the set takes 10 seconds, with no rest between lifts, you have 30 seconds to recover before beginning the next set.

Comment: That is how these phrases are *normally* used.  But we cannot know for certain whether your exercise instructor is using the phrases as most people do, or using "on the minute" as if it were synonymous with "after a minute".  If you could injure yourself by not taking sufficient rest between sets, best to seek clarification.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the sentences mean the following:

*After you complete the excercise, you can do it again on the minute.*

You do the exercise within a minute. Then you rest till the next minute begins. You do the exercise again.

*After you complete the excercise, you can do it again after a minute.*

You do the exercise. It doesn't matter how long it takes. Then you rest for a minute. You repeat the exercise thereafter.